# Flutter Form Autovalidate is firing at first time

Tags: flutter

I'm getting an error when the application is launched at first time all textfields are validating but It must not be like this, I took the form example from flutter documentation and I added the autovalidate:true, Appereantly on web it works but with a physical device and emulator it's not working, the error and the code is below

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

   return MaterialApp(
    title: appTitle,
    home: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(appTitle),
     ),
     body: MyCustomForm(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}


class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {

 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Form(
    autovalidate:true,
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please enter some text';
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {                
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {  
                Scaffold.of(context)
                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
              }
            },
            child: Text('Submit'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**To stop** *autovalidate* at first time we should use ***autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,***  instead of **autovalidate=true**. Since **autovalidate** has *deprecated* . So use like this:-

Define GlobalKey as:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

On Scaffold use this.

```
child: new Form(
              key: _formKey,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              child: FormUI(),
            ),
```

Comment: I have a problem with this validation method, is working just the first time when i press the button, then the validation is not working for some fields. I realised this is just happening with ListView, not Column. I think it's because widget rebuilds.

Comment: @JohanOrdenesGalleguillos I have no idea about ListView. I will check it .I have used in Column.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an autoValidate bool variable which will be false by default so no validation message is shown.When user presses the submit button it will check for validation and if invalid it will set the autoValidate variable to true and show validation errors.It will autovalidate as soon as user overcomes validation issues else it will submit the form normally.

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}


class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _autoValidate=false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Form(
      autovalidate:_autoValidate,
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                }else{
                  setState(() {
                    _autoValidate=true;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use that solution I don't have the autovalidation in real time, I don't want that, I want the autovalidate:true, but not at first time like is exposed here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15404

Comment: I use this code and I do get realtime autovalidation if user has submitted the form incorrectly for the first time .Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, but I wanted use the autovalidate from the beginning for each field but I see it's a flutter's bug, I'm going to do it as you said, thanks

Comment: What a mission - Flutter needs to fix this. I left a comment on the ticket for this. I am baffled how a framework can have this issue, the field needs to be validated after the user left it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autovalidate from the beginning for each field you may consider this solution but it's hectic as you'll have to create booleans for each TextFormField you are having.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}


class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _autoValidate=false;
  bool _validateFieldOne=false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Form(
      autovalidate:_autoValidate,
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            autovalidate: _autoValidate,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                _validateFieldOne=true;
              });
            },

          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                }else{
                  setState(() {
                    _autoValidate=true;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `_validateFieldOne` is not being used in this answer

Answer (score -1):

Here `_validateFieldOne` is the stateful variable used to check the validated state of form field. Such that you may use variables for each of form fields.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}


class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _validateFieldOne = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            autovalidate: _validateFieldOne,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                _validateFieldOne = true;
              });
            },

          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```